# Switching back to old cPanel on another hosting package

Tags: hosting, cpanel, nameservers

I have a HostGator hosting package and recently decided to move to a new hosting package with SimpleServers.

The move was completed successfully, however I have decided to move back to HostGator, for reasons I won't disclose here.

So - here's the situation: I have a cPanel with SimpleServers now and I also have a cPanel for HostGator. The files/directories are present on both servers.

To get my site pointing back to HostGator, do I simply change the nameservers for my domain to HostGator's nameservers? Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You are right. You will have to change only nameserver, If your accounts is present on HostGator server and that account files has a updated site contents.

If your account files are old then first you will have to upload your updated site content to HostGator server and then change your Name-server.